# Layers are not visible after restarting GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, enterprise-geodatabase, layers

I have ArcSDE connection on GeoServer. In order to make GeoServer faster I have restarted it. After restarting my published layers (datas) are not visible. When I publish this layer again, GeoServer says that "you already published this layer"

How can I see my published layers after restarting GeoServer.

Comment: This is most probably not a Geoserver, but a server permissions problem. We had similar problems (our installation lost some, but not all settings after every reboot), it turned out that our installation lacked the necessary rights to write all of its config files.

Comment: Further to SAnderka's comment, take a look in the geoserver.log file. It should indicate what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for replies. SAnderka and GIS-Jonathan It was also about permissions problems. Now looking for solving this issue.